# Exchange 2010 - Moderate mails sent to Distribution Group "All employees" by sender manager

Tags: exchange-2010, rules

In Exchange 2010 we can moderate mails sent to a distribution list, directly from the distribution list parameters. It is the same moderators for all the senders.

This is perfect except that wen cannot choose different moderators for different senders.

There is a second option, with Transport Rules, but it cannot moderate mails sent to distribution groups. This allows to moderate somes users by some moderators and other users by other moderators but can only moderate mails sent to, for instance, external recipients, or some recipients but not to a distribution group. This is sad because this option is very good because it allows to "forward the message to the sender's manager for moderation".

So, here is my question, how could I manage to set moderation for a distribution group but moderators are respective managers of the senders?

Do I really have to set a huge transport rule saying: if mails are sent to each of the 300 employees then send the mail to the manager for moderation? This is nearly impossible, if it doesn't crash while adding the 300 users.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, the email messages which are sent from all the senders to the distribution group will be moderated by the same moderators. There aren’t any other features to realize your requirement in the settings of distribution group, not being set different moderators for different senders in the distribution group is probably by design:

[image]

To my knowledge, it seems that you could only set transport rules for the different senders and different moderators to moderate different senders. According to **Manu**’s solution in the similar thread "**[Message Approval to group, different moderator for different sender](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17799e4f-c7c7-464f-a439-3bb8f01c50be/message-approval-to-group-different-moderator-for-different-sender?forum=exchangesvrsecuremessaging)**", you could create the following transport rules in the EMC(**When the recipient’s address includes the distribution group, and the sender’s address includes sender@domain.com, forward the message to one specified moderator’s address to moderate**):

[image]

After that, the moderator Administrator@contoso.com will receive the moderation message, if I approve/reject the email, the email will be approved/rejected, and you could set more rules for different senders and moderators:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer that looks promising. I didn't think about "recipients contains"... When I test, the Message is sent without moderation. Maybe I have to wait some sync time after adding the transport rule? I wonder if it is case sensitive and special char aware

Comment: Try to remove your current moderators in the distribution group moderation. If not, the message will still be moderated by the group moderation instead of transport rule.

Comment: Already done. I'm testing with a distribution group with no moderator. Transport Rule is priority 0 (first priority), enabled. When I'm on Actions part of rule creation, there is a message talking about RMS. I'm not sure what it means exactly: Rights Management Service (RMS) is a premium feature that requires an Exchange Enterprise Client Access License (CAL) for each user mailbox. Do you know if it implies anything here?

Comment: Ok, its just for the "rights protect message with RMS template" action. http://techgenix.com/rights-management-server-exchange-2010-part6/

Comment: If I setup the rule to act on recipients which are normal mailboxes and not a distribution group, it works. So, the problem must be related to distribution groups.

Comment: I found the solution. Same mistake again... Must use "when any of the recipients in the To field is"... It works with "Mail Universal Security Group" and "Mail Universal Distribution Group". This is awesome... Some much try and fail and time to find this. So sad all the different options don't work the same with distribution groups...